# Calculate Full Months Between Two Dates in MS ACCESS Query

Tags: date, ms-access

I'm having an issue using the ACCESS DateDiff function.  I'm attempting to obtain the FULL months between two dates however this function ignores dates in the middle of the month.  It apparently performs a simple calculation on the month number itself and does not take into account the day of the month.

**For example**: If I want to know the full month between October 16th and November 3rd.  This should return zero however the DateDiff function is returning 1.  What code do I need to implement in order to obtain the full months between and have it work for ALL months.  I say ALL months as months can have 28 days (29 in a leap year), 30 days and 31 days which is why I wouldn't simply calculate the days between two dates.

> `Access Function:` DateDiff("m",PAID_DATE,STATIC_DATE) AS Months_Between

The screenshot below shows the data I want as well as the incorrect month between results I am obtaining.

[image]

Lastly a screenshot of a simple representation of my output in the ACCESS Design View.

[image]

**Oracle Example of what I'm trying to accomplish in ACCESS**

I can accomplish this in `Oracle` very easy as oracle's `Months_Between` function takes into account the months and leap years and the days within each month and outputs the actual months between value.  If I knew how to get this in ACCESS I wouldn't have posted this question.

[image]

Comment: If you don't want to use just days and the "average" number of 30 days per month, how do you reconcile what "full month" means when on the limits of months with different number of days? What is your precise rule for this? It can't strictly be how many days since month lengths fluctuate. But if it is about the start and ending day of the month, there are possible contradictions. So is 9/30/18 to 10/30/18 a full month even though 10/31 is the last day of Oct? How about 10/31/18 to 11/30/18, since it started on 31 but Nov doesn't have 31 days?

Comment: @CPerkins Noted:  I have reduced the image.  I forgot not everybody is viewing these posts on a Vertical Monitor.  I've also updated my post with how I would do this in Oracle.  I work in Oracle 90% of the time and honestly hate working in ACCESS but sometimes we have to do things we don't like :)  You can see that the ACCESS equivalent DateDiff function does not output it's months between value the same as Oracle.  This is causing me grief I do not encounter when working in Oracle.

Comment: The Oracle info indirectly answered the questions I asked about boundary dates.  See [this question](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:53374949268527).  The first part lists a reasonable set of rules that could be used to get "full months", but if you keep reading it shows that even the Oracle function has inconsistent results.  Near the end, notice one conclusion that `"months" are NOT a fixed unit of time`.  Obviously the Access DateDiff() function is not useful alone, so it boils down to you'll have to write your own function that implements your rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a custom function like this:

```
Public Function Months( _
  ByVal datDate1 As Date, _
  ByVal datDate2 As Date, _
  Optional ByVal booLinear As Boolean) _
  As Integer

' Returns the difference in full months between datDate1 and datDate2.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   negative differences
'   leap years
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'   negative date/time values (prior to 1899-12-29)
'
' Optionally returns negative counts rounded down to provide a
' linear sequence of month counts.
' For a given datDate1, if datDate2 is decreased stepwise one month from
' returning a positive count to returning a negative count, one or two
' occurrences of count zero will be returned.
' If booLinear is False, the sequence will be:
'   3, 2, 1, 0,  0, -1, -2
' If booLinear is True, the sequence will be:
'   3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3
'
' If booLinear is False, reversing datDate1 and datDate2 will return
' results of same absolute Value, only the sign will change.
' This behaviour mimics that of Fix().
' If booLinear is True, reversing datDate1 and datDate2 will return
' results where the negative count is offset by -1.
' This behaviour mimics that of Int().

' DateAdd() is used for check for month end of February as it correctly
' returns Feb. 28. when adding a count of months to dates of Feb. 29.
' when the resulting year is a common year.
'
' 2010-03-30. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim intDiff   As Integer
  Dim intSign   As Integer
  Dim intMonths As Integer

  ' Find difference in calendar months.
  intMonths = DateDiff("m", datDate1, datDate2)
  ' For positive resp. negative intervals, check if the second date
  ' falls before, on, or after the crossing date for a 1 month period
  ' while at the same time correcting for February 29. of leap years.
  If DateDiff("d", datDate1, datDate2) > 0 Then
    intSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", DateAdd("m", intMonths, datDate1), datDate2))
    intDiff = Abs(intSign < 0)
  Else
    intSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", DateAdd("m", -intMonths, datDate2), datDate1))
    If intSign <> 0 Then
      ' Offset negative count of months to continuous sequence if requested.
      intDiff = Abs(booLinear)
    End If
    intDiff = intDiff - Abs(intSign < 0)
  End If

  ' Return count of months as count of full 1 month periods.
  Months = intMonths - intDiff

End Function
```

Comment: It's a thing of beauty.  This small piece of code makes it look easy.  Worked like a charm.