# Dates criteria for dates 11 to 12 months previous to todays date

Tags: ms-access

I'm making a query that needs to show dates for members that signed up between 11 months and a year ago from todays date so that the user can tell what members need to renew their membership and I'm not sure how to accomplish this in the criteria area

Answer (score 0):

For full months, that could be:

```sql
Where DateDiff("m", [SignUpDate], Date()) Between 11 And 12
```

If you need per the exact date, it takes some more:

[Calculate Full Months Between Two Dates in MS ACCESS Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52995856/3527297)

Using that function, the criteria will be:

```sql
Where Months([SignUpDate], Date()) Between 11 And 12
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply but that unfortunately is only showing me the month that rather than a 30 day period. Any ideas how I can get it to show me the dates that were between 365 days before todays date and 335 days before todays date?

Comment: Yes, see edited answer and the included link, please.